# css scrollbar width and round effect

Tags: css

is there a way where I can set the width of the default width of the scroll bar in a dive ?
what I have is a div with auto scroll bar. what I want to  set the width of the scroll bar as a thin line and hide the both top and bottom arrow marks of this.

Comment: Please add some code - HTML and CSS will do the trick, cheers !

Comment: See the examples plugin: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Answer (score 27):

You can use CSS's WebKit functionalities:

You can read about it [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

For example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px     rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px     rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Would create an iOS-like scrollbar ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Prxsj/))

Good luck

Comment: thanks for advice but do i need to inclulde something else to this to work. i have inculded the about css part to my css file but nothing is chnaged in the scroolbar. part of my css as bellow ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

Comment: @rushd: Well, you need your other elements to respond to it. Please check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Prxsj/) which I tested and works. If you can't see a changed scrollbar; the browser you are using is too old to display it. If you **can** see it: look at the implementation: that's how you should implement it as well. Good luck!